# Laravel can't find method

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a `GET` request to:

```
/review/response
```

The route is present in the `php artisan route:list` with other two working routes to that controller, so controller is fine.

[image]

Here is a part of my controller code:

[image]

But when accessing to that route, this is the response I get:

[image]

I already run `composer du` and `php artisan route:clear`

All other methods in that controller are working, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your route should be like:

```
Route::get('review/response', ['as' => 'review.action', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReviewController@action']);
```

The problem is in your **namespace**. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace should be following :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers
```

Comment: this was also helpful, but I think the second one could be more helpful for others. thank you!